# GET URL from pages that access my Image

Tags: php, html

Imagine any webpage ex: example1.com/something... using this html:

```
<img src="http://www.example2.com/controller/showImage" >
```

My controller in web2.com is something like:

```
function showImage() {
   getIP();                             //return USER IP (working)
   getURL();                            //return example1.com/something... (not working it returns always 'http://www.example2.com/controller/showImage')
   addMetricsSQL($ip, $url);              //add ip and url in database (working)
   header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');  //headers
   readfile($this->$path_img);        //a path
}
```

My current function is:

```
public function getURL() {
        $ssl      = ( ! empty( $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' );
        $sp       = strtolower( $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] );
        $protocol = substr( $sp, 0, strpos( $sp, '/' ) ) . ( ( $ssl ) ? 's' : '' );
        $port     = $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'];
        $port     = ( ( ! $ssl && $port=='80' ) || ( $ssl && $port=='443' ) ) ? '' : ':'.$port;
        $host     = ( false && isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'] ) ) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'] : ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : null );
        $host     = isset( $host ) ? $host : $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $port;
        return $protocol . '://' . $host . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    }
```

But like I said, it only returns example2.com/controller/showImage

My questions:

- Is posible to get the right URL(in this case
  example1.com/something...) using PHP?
- How the getURL() function should be?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Dump $_SERVER and see what is in there. If there is nothing there You out of luck

Comment: There is some other problem. You have hard-coded '://' in the return, so it must return that. If you said it is returning '://example2.com/...', then you might be looking at the correct problem. Since you claim it doesn't return '://' at all, the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Dumped server.. no luck.. But not convinced thats imposible.
About the url format its ok. The problem is that Im getting the image url, not the server loading the img. This is what Im trying to fig this out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was painfull but the answer to my question is:

```
public function getURL() {
        return getenv('HTTP_REFERER', true) ?: getenv('HTTP_REFERER');
    }
```

**HTTP_REFERER** Makes all the magic.